# Unusual app flow when closing my android app

Tags: android

Each time I try closing my android application. I notice that when I close the close key on my android emulator close to the menu key. My app would display all the view that I have visited . It kind of weird to cos there is a default page that I expect that when the user gets to if the terminate key is pressed it should close. Well I am suppose to always call the finish() to prevent android from remember every activity that as been viewed when running the application.

Please how to I go about this.

Comment: "My app would display all the view that I have visited" what does it mean?

Comment: supposing my app as contact Activity, about Activity and home activity. and the default page that the user is surppose to see is home activity. So if while running the app I visited about activity 10 times and I try to close the app by navigating to home and close since it is the default activity. My app would simply navigate back to all the activities that I have opened while I was using it before it closes finally.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Instead of

```
startActivity(intent);
```

then implement "onActivityResult" and finish the app from it by calling

```
finish();
```

and do that for all your sub activities.

Comment: But I dont intent returning a value. I though startActivityForResult should be used when returning a value.

Comment: when you finish() the sub activity it will call (onActivityResult) in the main one so you can finish it also.

Comment: So Please what would I put in the onActivityResult in the main activity. I am a little confused. How do I finish it in this method to.  @MoradEdwar

Comment: put on it finish() and do that for any Activity you want it to never came again when the user end a sub Activity.